# App closed when it asks permission to user for read write

Tags: java, android-studio, android-permissions

I am facing issues in my app, My app needs read write permission but whenever my app opens first time my app crashes and closed then it asks for permission in background then i need to start it again then it works fine. I am getting issues only first time run.

This is my code

Main Activity

```
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkPermissions();
    }


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private void checkPermissions(){

    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            // Explain to the user why we need to read the contacts
        }

        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                1052);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is an
        // app-defined int constant that should be quite unique

        return;
    }
     /*   if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != android.content.pm.PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED||
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        != android.content.pm.PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{
                            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                            android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    },
                    1052);*/



}
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {

    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1052: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == android.content.pm.PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && grantResults[1] == android.content.pm.PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Enjoy This app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {

                android.widget.Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied, without your permission we cant share or download images to your device", android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // Permission denied - Show a message to inform the user that this app only works
                // with these permissions granted
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask for permission by starting a new activity and writing all the above code in that new activity. I replicated this problem in a new android project and verified this.

What you need to do is create another activity, one that is specifically created to ask for permissions. Let it be Main2Activity.java. Your MainActivity.java would be

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class));
    }
}
}
```

Then your Main2Activity.java would be

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkPermissions();
    }
}
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private void checkPermissions(){

    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            // Explain to the user why we need to read the contacts
        }

        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                1052);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is an
        // app-defined int constant that should be quite unique

        return;
    }
 /*   if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != android.content.pm.PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED||
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    != android.content.pm.PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                        android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                },
                1052);*/



}
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {

    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1052: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && (grantResults[0] == android.content.pm.PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    || grantResults[1] == android.content.pm.PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED))
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Enjoy This app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
            else {

                android.widget.Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied, without your permission we cant share or download images to your device", android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // Permission denied - Show a message to inform the user that this app only works
                // with these permissions granted
            }
        }

    }
}
}
```

Notice that in Main2Activity.java, i made edits

```
if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && (grantResults[0] == android.content.pm.PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    || grantResults[1] == android.content.pm.PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED))
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Enjoy This app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
```

1. For the Toast to appear, android.content.pm.PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED will be either in grantResults[0] or grantResults[1] but not both.
2. I used functions startActivity() and finish() because after getting permission this activity made specifically for permission will close and open the MainActivity.java.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26401388)

Comment: @AlexanderUshakov Thank you for the pointing that out. I have now replicated the problem and provided the best case answer. Is this ok now?